# Processing a company list in which every element is an employee list

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

Now, there is a company list in which an element is an employee list in every company. I calculate the salary of employees in every company with a RESTful API one by one,. This is very slow, so I join 1000 elements to one list and post it to the service.

```
import requests


def _calculate_employee_salaries(employees):
    response = requests.post(url, json={"input": employees})
    salaries = parse_response(response)
    return salaries


def get_calculate_employee_salaries(company_employees_lis):
    begin, step = 0, 1000
    company_employee_salaries_lis = []
    while begin < len(company_employees_lis):
        employees = []
        employee_num_lis = []
        for comp_employees in company_employees_lis[begin:(begin+step)]:
            employees.extend(comp_employees)
            employee_num_lis.append(len(comp_employees))
        salaries = _calculate_employee_salaries(employees)

        idx = 0
        for num in employee_num_lis:
            company_employee_salaries_lis.append(salaries[idx:(idx + num)])
            idx += num
        begin += step
    return company_employee_salaries_lis


if __name__ == "__main__":
    company_employees_lis = [["employees_id_1", "employees_id_2", "employees_id_3"], ["employees_id_4"], ["employees_id_5", "employees_id_6"]]
    company_employee_salaries_lis = get_calculate_employee_salaries(company_employees_lis)
```

I think my code is bad, because I use a variable `employee_num_lis` to remember the number of employees in every company. And there must be clean, artful and pythonic code. This code is just a sample, not what I should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify this. Let's break down the algorithm needed for this:

1. Chain all employees into one stream
2. Chunk this stream into 1000 employees

   - For each chunk get the salaries
3. Distribute the salaries back again into the different companies

The first part can be done using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). The second one can use e.g. [this `grouper` recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12186183/4042267). And the final part can be easily done with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) if we keep everything before as generators.

```
from itertools import chain, islice
```

> ```
> def grouper(iterable, n):
>     it = iter(iterable)
>     return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(it, n)), ())
> ```

```
def get_salaries(employees):
    respone = requests.post(url, json={"input": employees})
    return parse_respone(respone)

def employee_salaries_per_company(company_employees):
    all_employees = chain.from_iterable(company_employees)       
    salaries = chain.from_iterable(get_salaries(employees)
                                   for employees in grouper(all_employees, 1000))
    return [list(islice(salaries, n)) for n in map(len, company_employees)]
```

---

Note that in english the plural of employee is employees and not emploices; and the plural of salary is salaries and not salarices.